# Separability of the ring extension $A \subset A[T]/(h_1,\ldots,h_n)$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, separable-algebras

Is there a generalization of Wang's known result, [Corollary 8](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869380902331), which says the following: $A \subset B=A[T]/(h(T))=A[w]=B$ is a separable ring extension if and only if $h'(w)$, the formal derivative of $h(T)$ evaluated at $w$, is an invertible element of $B$.

By a generalization I mean:

> $A \subset B=A[T]/(h_1(T),\ldots,h_n(T))=A[w]=B$ is a separable ring extension if and only if $?$.

I wish to find out what is $?$; perhaps it should say something like:
$h_1'(w),\ldots,h_n'(w)$ are invertible elements of $B$.

Please notice that [Theorem 7](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869380902331) is not what I am looking for.

**Remarks:** 
(1) My motivation: $w$ is algebraic over $A$ and $A$ is not necessarily a UFD (when $A$ is a UFD, we have $n=1$).
(2) Perhaps [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71869/an-r-algebra-a-is-r-separable-if-and-only-if-all-derivations-are-inner) is relevant.

Any remarks and hints are welcome!

Comment: I have just noticed that actually Wang answers my above question in his Theorem 5. The $?$ is: $h_1'(w),\ldots,h_n'(w)$ generate the unit ideal of $B$, in other words, there exist $b_1,\ldots,b_n \in B$ such that $b_1h_1'(w)+\cdots+b_nh_n'(w)=1$.